# String array in implemenation a Queue

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, queue

I'm currently studying data structure & i'm trying to make a string array in java using a queue. 
I want the user to inserts how many element then inserts them (example students name).
but the code won't work, can you help telling me where is the error?

```
package test;
import java.util.Scanner;
class queue{
    String arr[];
     int size;
    private int front;
    private int rear;
    private int items;
    queue(int s){
        size=s;
    String arr[]=new String[size];
        front=0;rear=-1;
        items=0;
    }
public void insert(int x){
if(rear==size-1){
rear=-1;
arr[++rear]=x;
items++;
}
}
public String remove(){
String temp=arr[front++];
if(front==size){
front=0;
items--;
}
return temp;
}
public boolean isEmpty(){
return (items==0);
}
public boolean isFull(){
return (items==size);
}
public int n(){
return items;
}}
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        queue ob=new queue(4);
        System.out.println("How many elements?");
        ob.size=in.nextInt();

         System.out.println("Enter names:");
               for( int i=0;i<ob.size;i++){ 
            ob.arr[i]=in.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("*** Names ***");
        for(int i=0; i<ob.size;i++){ 
            System.out.println(ob.arr[i]);
        }
    }}
```

i get this error for this line

```
arr[++rear]=x;
```

that says "int cannot be converted to string"

also when i run the code this error appears too : 
NullPointerException

***** Update ***** 
new code in main, **it works** :)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    int size;
    System.out.println("How many elements?");
     size=in.nextInt();
   queue ob=new queue(size);
     System.out.println("Enter names:");
           for( int i=0;i<size;i++){ 
        ob.arr[i]=in.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("*** Names ***");
    for(int i=0; i<size;i++){ 
        System.out.println(ob.arr[i]);
    }
}
```

and in the queue constructor:

```
arr=new String[size];
```

Comment: @azurefrog where exactly?

Comment: Java doesn't automatically convert types for you (usually, there are exceptions like auto(un)boxing), so you can't assign an `int` value to a `String` variable.  Instead use one of the conversion methods built into the language, e.g. `arr[++rear]=Integer.toString(x);`

Comment: @azurefrog thank you for this information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is a string array

```
String arr[]=new String[size];
```

and you are trying to insert a int into it. If you want to insert a int as string, use:

```
arr[++rear]=String.valueOf(x);
```

Comment: Thank you but i tried both ways & didn't work. when i run the code another error appears "NullPointerException"

Comment: this: 
ob.arr[i]=in.nextLine();

Comment: @Mariej at your constructor you initialized a local variable instead the member variable.`  String arr[]=new String[size];` should be `arr=new String[size];`

Comment: It worked, thank you so much! I also had to remove the 4 i put in the object i made.